# force the user's ie8 compatibility mode

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, ie8-compatibility-mode

Is it possible to force the client's IE8 to not be in Compatibility mode? I have a site where it looks good in compatibility mode, but of course not as good as IE8 - not to mention newer browsers. As I think about it, I believe it would not be possible, since it's the system setting, but maybe someone was struggling with that one before.

Thank you

Comment: Isn't compatibility mode the IE 5.5 mode?

Comment: IE8 with compatibility mode acts like IE7

Comment: Is there a public URL for the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole msdn site gives very good description [of compatibility modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

I suggest reading the information provided there as this will give you deeper understanding the topic, but if you want short answer, different modes are defined like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=4">   <!-- IE5 mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7.5" > <!-- IE7 mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100" > <!-- IE9 mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=a" >   <!-- IE5 mode --> 

<!-- This header mimics Internet Explorer 7 and uses 
     <!doctype> to determine how to display the webpage -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer does have a [compatibility mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/jj676915(v%3dvs.85)), you can enable it be using `x-ua-compatible` meta tag:

```html
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <!-- Have to positioned before scripts and style tags -->
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
</head>
```

Comment: The tag in HTML document: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`